# Get all Youtube url links using CSS selector

Tags: angularjs, css-selectors, iteration

I want to get all url links from my Youtube channel, but if I use CSS selector just `$("a")`, it returns only one link.  I am assuming because of Youtube uses Angularjs to render the content.  How do I get all links from Youtube channel using CSS selector?
https://www.youtube.com/user/humorean/videos

Comment: why you need all links?? you can use document.getElementByTagName('a'), but it will return all a tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to get all the url links for the video, you should use `document.querySelectorAll`
You can assign all  tag in an array variable list as below:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#channels-browse-content-grid .yt-lockup-title a");
```